# CefSharp loads really slow- takes 40 seconds to show up inside a WPF app in a specific customer's VM

Tags: wpf, cefsharp

We are running a WPF app and have CefSharp control embedded inside it.
The app works fine in most the machines but takes about 30-40 seconds to load in on a specific customer's VM.

We already tried:

1. CefSharp argument `no-proxy-server` set to 1
2. The [Minimal CefSharp example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample) loads up quickly (3-4 seconds).
3. Upgraded the Intel graphics driver
4. Enabled the CefSharp logs, but couldn't guess much from it. Here's the `debug.log` from a run which took > 40 seconds to show up:

```
[0512/090835.087:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(186)] 3FE40680: set chrome proxy config service to 3FD043C0
[0512/090835.115:VERBOSE1:webrtc_internals.cc(118)] Could not get the download directory.
[0512/090835.116:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(705)] MSM::InitializeMaybeAsync([this=3FD15080])
[0512/090835.117:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(705)] MDM::MediaDevicesManager()
[0512/090835.117:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(705)] MSM::MediaStreamManager([this=3FD15080]))
[0512/090835.739:VERBOSE1:pref_proxy_config_tracker_impl.cc(186)] 3FE41EE0: set chrome proxy config service to 3FD040F0
[0512/090840.931:VERBOSE1:video_capture_oracle.cc(96)] Capture size auto-throttling is now enabled.
[0512/090840.932:VERBOSE1:video_capture_oracle.cc(124)] Capture size auto-throttling is now disabled.
[0512/090840.933:VERBOSE1:capture_resolution_chooser.cc(205)] Recomputed snapped frame sizes: 1928x1013
[0512/090840.933:VERBOSE1:capture_resolution_chooser.cc(157)] Recomputed capture size from 640x360 to 1928x1013 (100% of ideal size)
[0512/090854.178:INFO:cpu_info.cc(53)] Available number of cores: 8
[0512/090854.221:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(705)] RFAOSF::Core() [process_id=4, frame_id=1]
[0512/090854.222:VERBOSE1:document.cc(3712)] Document::DispatchUnloadEvents() URL = <null>
[0512/090854.222:VERBOSE1:document.cc(3792)] Actually dispatching an UnloadEvent: URL = <null>
[0512/090854.231:VERBOSE1:media_stream_manager.cc(705)] RFAOSF::Core() [process_id=4, frame_id=1]
[0512/090854.248:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(189)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  54CA2018
  URL:                   
  context_type:           WEB_PAGE
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: WEB_PAGE
[0512/090854.249:VERBOSE1:script_context.cc(189)] Created context:
  extension id:           (none)
  frame:                  00000000
  URL:                   
  context_type:           UNSPECIFIED
  effective extension id: (none)
  effective context type: UNSPECIFIED
[0512/090854.249:VERBOSE1:dispatcher.cc(434)] Num tracked contexts: 1
[0512/090854.682:VERBOSE1:capture_resolution_chooser.cc(205)] Recomputed snapped frame sizes: 1928x1013
[0512/090854.769:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(365)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", 57020540:LayoutNGBlockFlow (positioned) ::before moved from "-555.25,0 723.438x4" to "-326.25,0 816.797x4" (visible from "0,0 168x4" to "0,0 491x4")
[0512/090854.770:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(547)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", viewport was 0.10056% impacted with distance fraction 0.118776 and subframe weighting factor 1
[0512/090854.770:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(626)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", layout shift of 0.000119441 reported; cumulative score is 0.000119441
[0512/090854.897:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(365)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", 57020540:LayoutNGBlockFlow (positioned) ::before moved from "-325.516,0 816.797x4" to "-59.5156,0 925.453x4" (visible from "0,0 491x4" to "0,0 866x4")
[0512/090854.898:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(547)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", viewport was 0.177362% impacted with distance fraction 0.137967 and subframe weighting factor 1
[0512/090854.898:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(626)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", layout shift of 0.000244701 reported; cumulative score is 0.000364142
[0512/090854.901:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(365)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", 57020540:LayoutNGBlockFlow (positioned) ::before moved from "-60.0469,0 925.453x4" to "-9.04688,0 946.047x4" (visible from "0,0 865x4" to "0,0 937x4")
[0512/090854.902:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(547)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", viewport was 0.191904% impacted with distance fraction 0.0264523 and subframe weighting factor 1
[0512/090854.902:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(626)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", layout shift of 5.07629e-05 reported; cumulative score is 0.000414905
[0512/090854.923:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(365)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", 57020F00:LayoutNGBlockFlow (relative positioned) DIV id='e85pk6q' class='form-group has-feedback formio-component formio-component-button formio-component-submit' moved from "35,114 1858x34" to "35,118 1858x38" (visible from "35,114 1858x34" to "35,118 1858x38")
[0512/090854.924:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(365)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", 5703C2C0:LayoutNGButton BUTTON class='btn btn-primary btn-md' moved from "35,114 69.5781x34" to "35,118 69.5781x38" (visible from "35,114 70x34" to "35,118 70x38")
[0512/090854.924:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(547)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", viewport was 3.99557% impacted with distance fraction 0.00207469 and subframe weighting factor 1
[0512/090854.924:VERBOSE1:layout_shift_tracker.cc(626)] in "local://formdisplay.html/", layout shift of 8.28956e-05 reported; cumulative score is 0.000497801
[0512/090901.150:VERBOSE1:statistics_recorder.cc(471)] Collections of all histograms
```

Comment: Nice log.  It tells you the three things that are chewing up most of the time.  Those log entries are at `090840.931`, `090854.178`, and `090901.150`, which consume 5 seconds, 9 seconds, and 6.5 seconds respectively.  The entire sequence appears to consume approximately 26 seconds.

Comment: The explanation could be as simple as heavy CPU load from other sources.  Antivirus scan, perhaps?  Norton is notorious for this.  Check your CPU loads on this VM using Task Manager.

Comment: What OS is the vm running? Does your application have an app.manifest?

Comment: @amaitland It's a Windows 10 VM. And yes, there are some antivirus & malware tools installed on the system. Could it be because of that?

And out app currently doesn't have a `app.manifest` file.

Comment: If the minimal example works then start by adding an app.manifest https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/101/NuGet/Readme.txt#L13 https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/blob/master/CefSharp.MinimalExample.Wpf/app.manifest#L50